# center horizontal RecyclerView in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am trying to set my horizontal RecyclerView in center of RelativeLayout. But  some of list items get center as I want and some of them are not set to center. It looks like this.
[image]

My XML is looking like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:textColor="?attr/TextColor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar"
        android:text="=: Change Your Font :="
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/appName"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:padding="@dimen/lblTime" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="?attr/TextColor"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_above="@+id/dialog_dismiss"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="7">


            <TextView
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/font_text_quote"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:autoLink="web"
                android:linksClickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/sample"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="@dimen/newMainText"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/hsv_font_bartextview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="visible" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>




    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_dismiss"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar"
        android:text="Dismiss"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="?attr/TextColor"
        android:padding="@dimen/lblTime"
        android:textSize="@dimen/appName"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/lblTime"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/lblTime"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Child Item XML is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@style/SelectableItemBackground"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="?attr/TextColor"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="hello"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="21sp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

My Java Code for it is like below

```
private void showGotoPageDialog() {

        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(SettingsActivity.this.getAssets(), constant.font);
        final Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(SettingsActivity.this);
        mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.font_dialogue);
        mDialog.getWindow().setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
                = new LinearLayoutManager(SettingsActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        hsv_font_bartextview= mDialog.findViewById(R.id.hsv_font_bartextview);
        hsv_font_bartextview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        final TextView font_text_quote;
        TextAdapterTextview textAdaptertextview = new TextAdapterTextview(SettingsActivity.this, Globle.getFontArray());
        hsv_font_bartextview.setAdapter(textAdaptertextview);

        font_text_quote= mDialog.findViewById(R.id.font_text_quote);
        font_text_quote.setTypeface(font);
        textAdaptertextview.setOnClickLIstner(new OnTClickLIstner() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v, String image, int position) {
                constant.font=image;
                Typeface newfont = Typeface.createFromAsset(SettingsActivity.this.getAssets(), constant.font);
                font_text_quote.setTypeface(newfont);

            }
        });

        mDialog.show();
        TextView dismiss = (TextView) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_dismiss);
        dismiss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mDialog.dismiss();
                Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Adapter Java codes

```
public class TextAdapterTextview extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TextAdapterTextview.MyViewHolder> {

    public OnTClickLIstner onClickLIstner;
    Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<String> dataSet;

    public TextAdapterTextview(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> data) {
        this.dataSet = data;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void setOnClickLIstner(OnTClickLIstner onClickLIstner) {
        this.onClickLIstner = onClickLIstner;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                           int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.text_view_raw_text, parent, false);
        //view.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.myOnClickListener);

        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {
        holder.textView.setText(Globle.getfontnames().get(listPosition));
        holder.textView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), dataSet.get(listPosition)));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataSet.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView textView;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (onClickLIstner != null) {
                onClickLIstner.onClick(v, dataSet.get(getAdapterPosition()), getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can see that the first two items put in center as well last two items also in center, but the third one is on top instead of center. Let me know if someone have idea to correct it.

**EDIT**
its setting in center correct when I scroll items and tap on item.

Thanks

Comment: this issue is not related to the activity/ fragment layout error, please set the recyclerview item layout, the recyclerView Adapter, and the code to initiate the recyclerview in onCreate to help you
these info is not enough to fix the problem

Comment: @AmjadOmari I have added java code related it. Please check it

Comment: and where is the adapter code please?

Comment: @AmjadOmari I have added adapter item xml code, Let me know if you are asking java code of it

Comment: yes the adapter java code. also try to avoid writing anything not elated to the issue, to minimize the question size.

Comment: @AmjadOmari I have added it. Please check it

Comment: please try to replace the third font asset with the second one just to check that if the problem is from the font asset or not

Comment: @AmjadOmari its still same :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155956/discussion-between-amjad-omari-and-priya).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar"

to android:layout_height="match_parent"

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/hsv_font_bartextview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="visible" />
```

this should be fixing the problem.

Comment: Yes sir ! It have solved the issue and Thanks a lot for help me to find issue even with TeamViewer. You are great :)

Answer (score 0):

For RelativeLayout the gravity attribute is set by:

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```